# FDT - How do I get my IOS project to package and compile in standard mode

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, fdt

I am just getting into testing my first ISO app using FDT and Actionscript there. I have everything configured correctly I think. In the debug configurations for IOS debugging I have Standard Packaging selected and when debugging I get the following error.

```
Packaging command: /Users/mwallace/Development/sdks/flex/flex_sdk_4.6.0.23201B/bin/adt
    -package
    -target
    ipa-debug
    -connect
    192.168.5.208
    -storetype
    pkcs12
    -keystore
    ../../../../../dev_certs/MWallaceCert.p12
    -storepass
    *************
    -provisioning-profile
    ../../../../../dev_certs/Snapverse.mobileprovision
    /Users/mwallace/Development/dev/wiretree/snapverse/apps/ScrollingListTest/deploy/ScrollingListTest.ipa
    bin/ScrollingListTest-app.xml
    -C
    bin
    ScrollingListTest.swf
Packaging failed!
Packaging error message: 
Compilation failed while executing : as
```

However if I selecte "Fast" for debugging all seems to work just fine and I can deploy the app to my phone and run it. It's just super slow when running it.

Comment: Which AIR SDK are you using? Perhaps try a different one. Does it work with ANT or command line?

Comment: AIR 3.2 ... never used at or commandline for this. is there a good resource you can point me to ?

Comment: Try a different AIR SDK. For reference, I can only suggest Adobe's docs: http://goo.gl/AsbR6

Comment: I updated to AIR 3.3 and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found that upgrading my AIR SDK to 3.3 fixed the issue.